# Return image tag with image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `react-globe` to render markers around the world, I'm having trouble rendering a given image for each marker. Using:

```
function markerTooltipRenderer(marker) {
  return `<img src=${marker.image} alt=${marker.city} />`;
}
```

is returning `[object Object]`, instead of the image. If I wrap the image tag in back-ticks, it simply returns the image tag as a string.

How can I properly render the image in the tooltip on hover of the marker?

[image]

Current implementation: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-globe-custom-marker-renderer-forked-bnkpj?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: @DBS — The function starts with a lower case letter so it isn't a component so… ‍♂️

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Look like you got this..

Comment: @DBS - I was returning a string there to show what the markup is that should be return, but I want it to render the string as the markup (image). The library `react-globe`, uses that function to return the data for the tooltip. If you take a look at the example codepen, and just return `marker.city` for example, you'll see it return the associated country name on hover of a tooltip. I just can't get it to return the rendered image associated with that tooltip.

Comment: @MoshFeu Looks like I've got what?

Comment: I doubt this is possible, in the documentation the signature for the render is to return a string, not HTML or JSX: https://react-globe.netlify.app/props

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the `img` tag right away so I thought you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an `Image` element (instead of jsx element or string)

```js
const markerTooltipRenderer = (marker) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = marker.image;
  return img;
}
```

Basically this function should return a DOM element so it can also be a `div` with any content inside.

For example

```js
const markerTooltipRenderer = (marker) => {
  const tooltipContent = document.createElement("div");
  tooltipContent.innerHTML = `
    <img src="${marker.image}" />
    ${marker.city}
  `;
  return tooltipContent;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-globe-custom-marker-renderer-forked-j6f1r?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Very cool, thanks! How could I format this so that I can provide a label under the image of the location?

Comment: How can I pass in `marker.city` so that the tooltip renders the name of the city and the image associated with it?

Comment: Ah, I was close. Thank you!